# Calculating $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}(e^{-k}-e^{-k-1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Pretty basic question - I'm just not that experienced with calculating summations and would love help with understanding the steps involved (I computed it with Mathematica but couldn't see the steps there). I'm not sure if I can distribute the sum, or if I can coerce this to use the Taylor series for $e^x$. Thanks!

Comment: It is the difference of two converging geometric series. As soon as $|r|<1$, $$\sum_{k\geq 1} r^k = \frac{r}{1-r}.$$ The Taylor series of the exponential function is not that relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}(e^{-k}-e^{-k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (2e)^{-k} \left( 1- e^{-1}\right)= \left(1 - \frac{1}{e}\right) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2e)^k}.
$$

Can you finish the problem from here?